# Logging process details of those that spike the CPU

Tags: cpu, performance, process

Something on my laptop is maxing out the CPU now and then. It's an i7 so I assume it must have to be a relatively big issue for that to be the case. When it happens, my laptop locks up for a few seconds, audio sounds very strange (I imagine it's looping really fast).

When it happens, I fire up task manager and can see the spike, but the option to sort by processor consumption descending and take a look at what it is has gone (it suddenly drops).

Is there anything out there that can be configured to log process details of any process that pushes the CPU over X where X, in this case, is probably 95% or so.

Comment: use [WPRUI to capture CPU usage and WPA to analyze it](https://superuser.com/a/1033720/174557).

Comment: Or the [Process Monitor](https://superuser.com/a/453916/536969).

Answer (score 1):

[Process Explorer](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/processexplorer.aspx)

> The unique capabilities of Process Explorer make it useful for
>   tracking down DLL-version problems or handle leaks, and provide
>   insight into the way Windows and applications work.

[image: Process Explorer]

Comment: Thanks for that. Do you know how specifically to log what I've asked, though? I don't believe your question is self-contained; you rely on a link that may go down.

Comment: I have updated picture with higher resolution one. You can mouse over CPU usage graph and look what process was using the most CPU resources at that time.